# How to create some kind of Splash screen/Launching screen, which disappears after App loaded? (React Native)

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I was wondering how to solve a launching screen which, let´s say it appears for some seconds and then gets replaced by the other View?

I would like to use this when the app is started the first time and to cover some networkings.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is how I solved the **Loading Screen**. I worked with Navigator Component.

In my `index.android.js` I set the `initialRoute` to my **SplashPage/SplashScreen** class and then in there I set a timeout which links to the **MainView** you want to jump to after a certain time.

**My Navigator in index.android.js:**

```
<Navigator
   initialRoute={{id: 'SplashPage'}}
   renderScene={this.renderScene}
   configureScene={(route) => {
       if (route.sceneConfig) {
           return route.sceneConfig;
       }
       return Navigator.SceneConfigs.HorizontalSwipeJump;
   }}
/>
```

**My initialRoute Class:**

```
class SplashPage extends Component {

    componentWillMount () {
        var navigator = this.props.navigator;
        setTimeout (() => {
            navigator.replace({
                id: 'MainView', <-- This is the View you go to
            });
        }, 2000); <-- Time until it jumps to "MainView" 
    }
    render () {
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
                <Image style={{position: 'absolute', left: 0, top: 0, width: windowSize.width, height: windowSize.height}} source={require('image!splash_screen')}></Image>
            </View>
        );
    }
}

module.exports = SplashPage;
```

**EDIT**

Might be more interesting because it is "native" ;) 
https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen

Comment: Image must be change after view fully loads, not after hard coded time

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 7):

Fixed this problem.
So what need to be done.

1) Make all from [this](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/) but don't create SplashActivity.

2) All what you need to do now is to set you MainActivity theme to SplashTheme.

Thing in that when MainActivity loading it showing it's theme, but after it replaced with React-Native stuff.

Comment: Best solution in my opinion, just to mention that the react-native main component must have a backgroundColor as the react app is on top of the splash.

Comment: @Andrey how come you didn't have to do the `SplashActivity` class stuff they do in the article you linked in step 1?

Answer (score 2):

I managed to do it this way, which looks like the simplest and needs less resources:

1. Create the splash images for the different resolutions. I used [ionic resources](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/icon-splashscreen.html) to generate all sizes from the PSD file. You need to create a temporary ionic project with `ionic start`, edit the PSD files inside /resources, and run `ionic resources`.
2. Place them in the appropriate folder in app/src/main/res/mipmap-xxx, with name ic_splash.png
3. Create app/src/main/res/drawable/splash.xml with this content:

   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item>
     <bitmap
       android:gravity="center"
       android:src="@mipmap/ic_splash"/>
   </item>
   </layer-list>`

   Note: Looks like some people needs to add a color below the bitmap item, so you just add `<item android:drawable="@android:color/black"/>` before the above `<item>`. The color doesn't really matter unless your splash image has transparency.
4. Add to app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml:

   `<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
       <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
   </style>`
5. Edit app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml and include inside application>activity `android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"`
6. Now the app will start with the splash screen as a background, and as soon as the React Native app loads it will be placed on top of it. The React Native main component should have some background so the splash image gets covered.

Comment: Work, but needed to add in splash.xml a color. e.g: `<item
  android:drawable="@android:color/black"/>`

Answer (score 2):

here is the solution,you can customise splashscreen with view animation using screen navigation

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';  import { View, Text, Animated,  
   Easing} from 'react-native';
export default class SplashPage extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.RotateValueHolder = new Animated.Value(0);
        setTimeout(() => {
            this.props.navigation.replace('login')
        }, 5000);
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.StartImageRotate();
    }
    StartImageRotate() {
        this.RotateValueHolder.setValue(0);
        Animated.timing(this.RotateValueHolder, {
            toValue: 1,
            duration: 3000,
            easing: Easing.linear,
        }).start(() => this.StartImageRotate());
    }

    render() {
        const RotateImage = this.RotateValueHolder.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 1],
            outputRange: ['0deg', '360deg'],
        });
        return (
            <View style={{
                flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'gray', alignItems: 'center',
                justifyContent: 'center'
            }}>
                <Animated.Image
                    style={{
                        width: 250,
                        height: 250,
                        transform: [{ rotate: RotateImage }],
                    }}
                    source={{ uri:'someurl.png' }}
                />
            </View>
        );
    } }
```

Comment: yes thats cool, but it is better to implement the splash screen native as with your and my solution there will still be a white screen when app is starting and before "SplashPage" is even mounted. =>  https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen

Comment: can i perform actions like animations and gifs with native splash screen? i got white screen before splash screen load

Comment: yeah, i am pretty sure you can do this. What exactly do you need? You want to have a Animation/GIF with react-native-splash-screen?

Comment: yes,i want splash screen with animation on multiple images.how can i perform with react-native-splash-screen?

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/) is the correct way.

Taking advantage of the `windowBackground` attribute should avoid all the UI artifacts that you could made if you were using the old style (launching an activity which runs for a determinate amount of time)

Comment: How would you apply this to react native ?

Comment: This is not a solution for react native