# How to set the splash screen for react-native android

Tags: android, react-native, splash-screen

How does one set a splash screen for react-native android, I can't find anything on the topic and I thought it was odd.

Thanks

Comment: Here is answer on your question http://stackoverflow.com/a/39298315/277345

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create some kind of Splash screen/Launching screen, which disappears after App loaded? (React Native)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33390013/how-to-create-some-kind-of-splash-screen-launching-screen-which-disappears-afte)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I had tried 3 of the following ways. The first one is what I am currently using for android splash screen for react-native projects.

1. Using a npm package written by other.

   reference: https://github.com/remobile/react-native-splashscreen
2. Create a `SplashScreen` component and redirect afterward.

   reference: [How to create some kind of Splash screen/Launching screen, which disappears after App loaded? (React Native)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33390013/how-to-create-some-kind-of-splash-screen-launching-screen-which-disappears-afte#answer-33390293)
3. Natively in `java` code.

   reference: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/

I have a `fetch` request in the `componentDidMount()` of `initialRoute`.

Using the first way from the list above performs the request while showing the splash screen.

Whereas the second way, needs to wait until the `SplashScreen` component get unmounted.

Third way is slightly more codes to write and maintain.

Comment: How Can I add Video Splash Screen in Android

Comment: how to make splash screen full screen for nokia 5.1 pluse ( and for other similar screen devices )

Answer (score 27):

This tutorial here works great - I quoted it and modified a bit, I added the `react-native-background-color` touch.

https://medium.com/react-native-development/change-splash-screen-in-react-native-android-app-74e6622d699 (which is based on this https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/ - so this is native Android technique)

> 1. You need to create splash screen in res/drawable. Let’s call it splash_screen.xml
>
>    ```
>    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
>
>        <item
>            android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>
>
>        <item>
>            <bitmap
>                android:gravity="center"
>                android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
>        </item>
>
>    </layer-list>
>    ```
> 2. Now you need to update res/values/styles.xml
>
>    ```
>    <resources>
>
>        <!-- Base application theme. -->
>        <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
>            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
>        </style>
>
>    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="AppTheme">
>            <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_screen</item>
>        </style>
>
>    </resources>
>    ```
> 3. Now open AndroidManifest.xml and replace `AppTheme` with `SplashTheme` in MainActivity
>
>    ```
>    <activity
>            android:name=".MainActivity"
>            android:label="@string/app_name"
>            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme"
>        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
>            <intent-filter>
>                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
>                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
>            </intent-filter>
>    </activity>
>    ```
>
>    We use SplashTheme instead of updating AppTheme, to add this background only to start activity and leave other stuff without changes.
> 4. After you try the above out, you will notice the splash screen will always stay under your js views. You have two options to hide the splash screen:
>
>    - Either use react-native-background-color module from https://github.com/ramilushev/react-native-background-color to set a color on the background which will remove the image. (This is the recommended way because when keyboard shows in some cases, it makes the root view visible for a split second.)
>    - Or set a solid (non-transparent) background color on your root view.

Note on what "root view" means. This is the very first `<View>` you render in your app that you control (meaning that you can style it).

#### Custom Color

If you want to use a custom color, other then `@android:color/***` then what you have to do is create `colors.xml` at `android\app\src\main\res\values\colors.xml` and define a colors like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="foobar">#ca949b</color>
</resources>
```

You can use whatever name and whatever color code.

Then back in `splash_screen.xml` we update `<item android:drawable="@android:color/white" />` to be `<item android:drawable="@color/foobar" />`

#### Extra info on removing the background splash image from behind

After you create a splash like this. You will notice that the image stays in the background forever. To remove this image use this module - https://github.com/ramilushev/react-native-background-color - and call `BackgroundColor.setColor('#XXXXXX')` with whatever color. It will remove the image.

Instead of using an opaque color on your root view to cover the splash, it is still recommended to use the above module, because when the keyboard shows, the background view shows for a split second.

Comment: Thank you @SeunLanLege! I just added how you can use "custom color" instead of the `@android:color/***` defaults.

Comment: Thank you this is  the easy way to add splash screen in android. 
but image where we placed

Comment: This was quick and easy, however on my android device the image is tiny.  Any way to make it bigger?

Comment: @mediaguru yes the above is using your launcher icon `@mipmap/ic_launcher`. To change this, in your `android/app/src/main/res/drawable` folder create an image called `splash.png`. Then in `splash_screen.xml` change `@mipmap/ic_launcher` to `@drawable/splash`. See here - https://github.com/Noitidart/Enter-The-Gunbook/blob/master/android/app/src/main/res/drawable/splash_screen.xml - please don't forget to upvote if this helped.

Comment: @Lavaraju please see my previous comment, it tells you how to use image. Please upvote solution if it helped.

Comment: This should be the marked as the right answer (mainly because of the medium tutorial).

Answer (score 12):

Did you try to use [this](https://github.com/bamlab/generator-rn-toolbox/blob/master/generators/assets/README.md)? I came across this a few days ago. Works fine on iOS but I haven't tested it yet on Android (it should be fine).
You should have node >= 6 and imageMagic installed. (for mac: `brew install imagemagic`)

```
npm install -g yo generator-rn-toolbox
yo rn-toolbox:assets --splash IMGAE --android
```

Comment: i just used launch icon command :D now this one! saved alot of my time

Comment: Wow!!! This is what I've been looking for. Thanks a lot for this. Just like ionic resources. I think this should be added to `react native` source code and documentation