# Remove Powerd by React Native launch screen

Tags: react-native

I'm using the latest React Native (0.61.5) and I just added my own launch screen. It works, but just before the launch screen launches, I get the [ProjectName] Powerd by React Native screen.

How do I remove the Powerd by React Native before my own launch screen?

Comment: Are you asking about iOS ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your scenario you need to add Splash Screen for both android and ios separately.

For Android : [Splash Screen Adding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35041707/how-to-set-the-splash-screen-for-react-native-android/44380138#44380138)

**Assuming that you are asking about iOS Default Splash Screen here's the solution:**

You need to generate your splash screen sizes for different mobile views. Here a few examples of splash screen generator sites you can use - [TiCons](http://ticons.fokkezb.nl/)

Once you are done generating the images, you should open your app in Xcode. Here are the steps to follow:

1. Go to your project folder and open your iOS project using XCODE
2. Inside your project you can see file called **LaunchScreen.xib** , Remove this file ( This is the default splash screen of iOS )

[image]

3. Click on your project folder, then go to the **TARGETS** section
4. Click on the General Tab on the top-left corner of your Xcode and scroll down to **App Icons and Launch Images**
5. Go to Launch Images Source and click Use **Asset Catalog**. Click on migrate.

[image]

6. Remove the text **LaunchScreen** from Launch Screen File
7. Go back to your project folder and open the **Images.xcassets** file. You should see **AppIcon** and **LaunchImage**.
8. Next, click on the **LaunchImage**, you should see this:

[image]

- Finally, drag the splash screen images that has been generated initially to the **Launch Image box**.

[image]

Comment: it is deprecated now.

Answer (score 5):

**My solution is :**

1- Open your project in `XCode`

2- Click `LaunchScreen.storyboard`

3- On the right menu, go to `Simulated Metrics` tab

4- Disable `Is Initial View Controller` option

Comment: but it is blank screen i need to add image now.